# wildcard queries with multiple fields in ES?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can anyone please tell me how can i write wildcard queries with multiple fields in elasticsearch i have searched a lot on this but some one told me to use query string or multi match but the problem in my case is query string is not working for me my code is given below for a single field wildcard query if anyone know anything about this please share some light on this

```
"query": {
      "wildcard" : { "places_area1.city.raw_wildcard" : last_wildcard_string }
 }
```

**UPDATE**
Mappings

```
"settings": {
        "index": {
          "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
              "synonym_wildcard": {
                "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                "filter": ["filter_wildcard"]
              },
              "synonym_term": {
                "tokenizer": "keyword",
                "filter": ["filter_term"]
              },
              "simple_wildcard": {
                "tokenizer": "whitespace"
              }
            },
            "filter": {
              "filter_term": {
                "tokenizer": "keyword", // here you have to write this only for tokenizer keyword but not for whitespace
                "type": "synonym",
                "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt",
              },
              "filter_wildcard": {
                "type": "synonym",
                "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt",
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      mappings : {
        places_area1: {
          properties:{
            area1         : {"type" : "string", "index": "analyzed", "analyzer": "simple_wildcard"},
            city         : {"type" : "string", "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "synonym_term"
              },
              "raw_wildcard": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "synonym_wildcard"
              }
            } },
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Thank You In Advance

Comment: what is your mapping for the field against which you are running the query? could you show us what you are trying to match like a sample document?

Comment: hey chintan can you pls do me a favor do you know how to write wildcard queries with multiple fields in ES ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["title", "description", "state"], 
      "query": "Ban*",
      "lowercase_expanded_terms": false
    }
  }
}
```

**Why** do you need `"lowercase_expanded_terms": false`?

Since you are using `keyword` and `whitespace` tokenizer, word *Bangalore* is indexed as *Bangalore* and while using `query string wildcard` `Ban*` is lowercased because it is default setting and ES is looking for words starting with *ban* and hence it does not find Bangalore. You could also resolve this by adding `lowercase` filter to your `mappings`

Also it was working previously because you did not specify any analzyer and by default ES uses `standard analzyer` and it internally uses `lowercase token filter`

Comment: hey so sorry i didnt checked your previous query correctly it worke man thanks a lot but can you tell me why we have to write this "lowercase_expanded_terms": false ??

Comment: also change your answer to previous one so tht i can accept it :)

Comment: glad I could help!! on a side note `ban*` wont match Bangalore, you might want to consider adding `lowercase` filter based on your requirement so that 'ban*` and `Ban*` both word match Bangalore

Comment: I added explanation for why do you need to use  `"lowercase_expanded_terms": false`

Comment: hey @ChintanShah25 please have a look at this question ??                                                                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844942/in-es-wildcard-v-s-query-string-for-querying-on-multiple-fields-which-one-is-fas

Comment: i got error: `"[query_string] query does not support [lowercase_expanded_terms]"`. After removing `"lowercase_expanded_terms": false`, got it correctly!