# In ES wildcard v/s query_string for querying on multiple fields which one is faster and why?

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello all i am trying to search for wildcard queries in ES, now to search across multiple fields i can have two approach first use query_string to search for the word.

```
{
    "query": {
       "query_string": {
            "fields": ["title", "description", "state"], 
            "query": "Ban*",
            "lowercase_expanded_terms": false
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

I can use a bool query in which i can write multiple wildcard queries to do that now my question is which one do you all think is fast and appropriate.

```
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {"query": {"wildcard": {"title": {"value": "Ban*"}}}},
        {"query": {"wildcard": {"description": {"value": "Ban*"}}}},
        {"query": {"wildcard": {"taste": {"value": "Ban*"}}}}
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lucene query string query simply translates the query string into a bool query which has these simple queries ( like match , wildcard , regexp ) etc.

Hence you should not see any difference.

Comment: yeah but i want to know which will be faster multi_match or query_string ??

Comment: Same thing dude. both decomposes the query into base queries and executes them

Comment: yea but time to process same query varies or not bro ??